# Besides "beer factory", does brewery mean something else?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the speaker is [saying](https://youtu.be/PN71-IEdZyQ?t=161)

> we went to a local **brewery** -
>   we go there nearly every Friday because it's a fantastic place for us to relax
>   while our children play.

And its official transcript verifies that.

as far as I know, brewery is a place where beer is made commercially. Is it an appropriate place where kids play?

In the context of the quotation, is *brewery* referring to the place where beer is made or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of *brewery* is correct.  It is a place where beer is made.

It may seem odd to have a children's play area at a brewery, but consider that *brewery* can refer to anything from a huge industrial factory, to a small craft operation, essentially a single pub which brews a small amount of beer on-site.  In recent years there has been an increase in provision of 'family-friendly' beer-related establishments, particularly within this craft beer scene.  See for example [this](https://www.vox.com/the-goods/2019/8/6/20754738/taproom-brewery-baby-family-friendly-children) or [this](https://www.parent.com/10-breweries-and-wineries-to-visit-with-kids-in-tow-because-yeah-you-can-do-that/) article.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. Does "craft beer scene" mean the scene when the worker/owner is brewing beer?

Comment: It is a slightly nebulous term to be honest.  You could see [wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craft_brewery_and_microbrewery).  It wouldn't necessarily be the owner personally doing the brewing in every single instance, but you're thinking in the right direction - it implies small, independent operations as opposed to big national or international corporations with industrial facilities.